# Append text on same line to the JEditorPane as html format

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane, htmleditorkit

I want to append **html** content in the `JEditorPane`, but when I append in this way it inserts a *line break* automatically at the end of existing text, how to avoid this.

```
JEditorPane pn = new JEditorPane();
pn.setContentType("text/html");
pn.setText("This is line 1");
...
//after some time
HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) pn.getDocument();
HTMLEditorKit kit = (HTMLEditorKit) pn.getEditorKit();
kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "<b>Hello</b>", 0, 0, null);
kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "World", 0, 0, null);
```

It is going to place a linebreak at the end of existing text, everytime `insertHTML()` is called. 
Is this a default behaviour?
If so how I can handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTMLDocument has methods

```
public void insertAfterStart(Element elem, String htmlText)
public void insertBeforeEnd(Element elem, String htmlText)
public void insertBeforeStart(Element elem, String htmlText)
public void insertAfterEnd(Element elem, String htmlText)
```

Where you can pass paragraph or character element (leaf) and html to be inserted

Comment: these functions require `Element` which require `id`. what if one Thread is going to append the text without id of element, But i want insertion just at *end of the document* without any complicated task

Comment: Also it does the default alignment as `center align` even i have no style. I got it by `insertBeforeEnd` with *elem* *body* tag.

Comment: +1 It solved the new line issue, but new issue is it automatically aligns new added html to center. I will accept when this issue solved

Comment: You can ty to get desired Element form htmlDocument.getCharacterElement(htmlDocument.getLenght()) or htmlDocument.getParagraphElement(htmlDocument.getLenght()) and insert after. I am not sure why it's center aligned. Could yu add SSCCE to the question to illustrate the behaviour?

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the best way, but you might try this:

```
pn.setText(pn.getText + "your text to add here");
```

Comment: it will not append the text if `contetType` is html

Comment: @aquestion But you set the content type to `"text/html"`, not only to `"html"` or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @ ifLoop  definatly i mean text/html, your answer will work only if content type is "text/plain"

Comment: @aquestion Ah okay, now I understand the problem, but I cannot provide any other tips here.